# gridview Stops working on all pages having a Masterpage with an IF Condition in the Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, infragistics

I'm trying to a Menu Item based on an IF condition, which checks the Boolean value of a Session Variable 'Has Access'. The Items gets added in accordance with the IF condition but the grids stop working (the vertical scroll of the grids disappear and the records are displayed beyond the page height).

I write this code on a Master-page client side, so all the pages having gridviews and having this masterpage stop functioning.

here's the javascript code that causes the problem for the pages

```
function mmLoadMenus() 
{
        if (window.mm_menu) 
           return;

window.mm_menu = new Menu("root",200,22,"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,sans serif",10,"#FFFFFF","#1D4352","#6691BB","#9CCEF3","left","middle",3,0,400,-5,7,true,false,true,0,false,true);

        mm_menu.addMenuItem("Reports", "location='Reports.aspx'");

        if ('<%=Session["Has_Access_"]%>')
        {
            mm_menu.addMenuItem("My&nbsp;Activity", "location='MyActivity.aspx'");
        }
}
```

Only when I put the above If check, does the code causes problem for the gridview pages, otherwise the menu-item is added without issues.

Thank YOu for your Help!

Comment: **'Has_Access_'** != **'Has_Access'**, just in case. Have you checked the browser logs when executing this code? What value does `<%=Session["Has_Access_"]%>` output in the client source? The only value that string will evaluate to false is for `<%=Session["Has_Access_"]%>` to be an empty string; i.e. `if('')` will evaluate to false

Comment: Check your generated javascript. It should have an error whose is breaking your datagrid javascript.

Comment: @cbayram  the output in the client source is 'True'... the session variable value really doesnt matter in this Problem, because even if I use an empty if (if ('True')), I still face the same issue with the grid

Comment: @maralfol 

the generated javascript does not have any error and the datagrids are not using any javascript.

the grids are in pages which use the masterpage and the masterpage contains the javascript function where i want to put this condition

Comment: @user1800795 Is it correct that the issue is caused by the second call to addMenuItem and that the if statement isn't relevant to the issue?  If so, you should look at what is being done in the addMenuItem method and may want to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 if ('<%=Session["Has_Access_"]%>' == 'true')
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: Sorry I already tried that, it didn't work either. Same problem with the grids remain